# Get Current Memory Available in Mashmallow

Tags: android

My Problem is about to get the current memory used and available in Android Device. It may be internal memory or external Sdcard. Also give the detail about which type of the permissions required to get the access the device physical memory.

Comment: try this<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451659/android-get-total-size-and-free-size-of-usb-device-memory>

Comment: permission READ/WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE

Comment: Thanks  Mr. Bansal  It works for me

Comment: My Another question is that if we have  internal memory and Sd card too than which memory info is provided.

Comment: It will always result device memory. I have no idea about sdcard.