# How to get an External storage sd card size (With Mounted SD card)?

Tags: android, storage, sd-card, android-external-storage

[Link :I worked on based on this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory)

I added this line to find the size (both Internal and External) size,

```
return availableExternalMemorySize/(1024*1024);
```

I tested in my Tablet. I am getting both Internal and External SD card size as,

In Internal Storage:

1. Total Memory --1007
2. Available Memory --683

In External Storage:

1. Total Memory -- 1763
2. Available Memory -- 1554

But in Tablet, I saw settings. An  External Storage size has 8GB. But it is showing me 1.7 GB around when I tested via programmatically.

What is the procedure to find an External storage size?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the external SD card's available "free" space to show a number which agrees with the Menu->Settings->SD card and phone storage's number, use the following code:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
double sdAvailSize = (double)stat.getAvailableBlocks()
                   * (double)stat.getBlockSize();
//One binary gigabyte equals 1,073,741,824 bytes.
double gigaAvailable = sdAvailSize / 1073741824;
```

Here is how you get internal storage sizes:

```
 StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());        
 long blockSize = statFs.getBlockSize();
 long totalSize = statFs.getBlockCount()*blockSize;
 long availableSize = statFs.getAvailableBlocks()*blockSize;
 long freeSize = statFs.getFreeBlocks()*blockSize;
```

Here is how you get external storage sizes (SD card size):

```
 StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());        
 long blockSize = statFs.getBlockSize();
 long totalSize = statFs.getBlockCount()*blockSize;
 long availableSize = statFs.getAvailableBlocks()*blockSize;
 long freeSize = statFs.getFreeBlocks()*blockSize;
```

---

*Short note*

Free blocks:

> The total number of blocks that are
>   free on the file system, including
>   reserved blocks (that are not
>   available to normal applications).

Available blocks:

> The number of blocks that are free on
>   the file system and available to
>   applications.

---

Here is how to detect whether SD card is mounted:

```
 String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
 if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) 
 {
   // We can read and write the media    
 } 
 else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) 
 {
    // We can only read the media     
 } 
 else 
 {
    // No external media
 }
```

Relevant documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html

Comment: I came here as `getAvailableBlocks()` is deprecated. It it doesn't work from KitKat onwards. It seems these values are negative if the size is too large. So, it's suggested to use `getAvailableBlocksLong()`.

Comment: Is **freeSize** in MB or bytes?

Answer (score 2):

```
 Use the
following code
it may
help

public void getInternalmemorySize() {
    StatFs stat_fs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    double avail_sd_space = (double) stat_fs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * (double) stat_fs.getBlockSizeLong();
    double GB_Available = (avail_sd_space / 1073741824);
    double GBTotal = ((double) stat_fs.getBlockCountLong() * (double) stat_fs.getBlockSizeLong()) / 1073741824;
    SDCardCheck();
    Log.e("Memory", "Available MB  Internal: " + GB_Available + "---" + GBTotal);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
static String getExternalSdCardSize() {
    File storage = new File("/storage");
    String external_storage_path = "";
    String size = "";

    if (storage.exists()) {
        File[] files = storage.listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                try {
                    if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(file)) {
                        // storage is removable
                        external_storage_path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!external_storage_path.isEmpty()) {
        File external_storage = new File(external_storage_path);
        if (external_storage.exists()) {
            size = totalSize(external_storage);
        }
    }
    return size;
}

private static String totalSize(File file) {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(file.getPath());
    long blockSize, totalBlocks;
    long avaiblockSize, availableBlocks;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
        avaiblockSize = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
        availableBlocks = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
    } else {
        blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
        avaiblockSize = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        availableBlocks = stat.getBlockSize();
    }
    Log.e("Memory", "Memory--external--" + (double) (blockSize * totalBlocks) / 1073741824 + "---" + (double) (avaiblockSize * availableBlocks) / 1073741824);
    return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
}

private static String formatSize(long size) {
    String suffix = null;

    if (size >= 1024) {
        suffix = "KB";
        size /= 1024;
        if (size >= 1024) {
            suffix = "MB";
            size /= 1024;
        }
    }
    size = size / 1024;
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(size));

    int commaOffset = resultBuilder.length() - 3;
    while (commaOffset > 0) {
        resultBuilder.insert(commaOffset, ',');
        commaOffset -= 3;
    }

    if (suffix != null)
        resultBuilder.append(suffix);
    return resultBuilder.toString();
}

Ther is
some calculation
behalf of
these Methods.

StructStatVfs[
f_bavail=81523,
f_bfree=81523,
f_blocks=242304,
f_bsize=32768,
f_favail=0,
f_ffree=0,
f_files=0,
f_flag=1038,
f_frsize=32768,
f_fsid=0,
f_namemax=1530
        ]

StructStatVfs[
f_bavail=1633375,
f_bfree=1641567,
f_blocks=3134770,
f_bsize=4096,
f_favail=767939,
f_ffree=767939,
f_files=804672,
f_flag=1038,
f_frsize=4096,
f_fsid=0,
f_namemax=255
        ]


Internal-

        3134770*4096/1024*1024*1024=11.957.10 1633375*4096/1024*1024*1024=6.23

External-
        81523*32768/1024*1024*1024=2.487 242304*32768/1024*1024*1024=7.39
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to account for the deprecation and cross-availability, I've made these methods.

```
public static long sdCardFree_bytes() {
    File   path        = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StatFs stat        = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long   free_memory = 0; //return value is in bytes

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        free_memory = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong() * stat.getBlockSizeLong();
    } else {
        free_memory = stat.getAvailableBlocks() * stat.getBlockSize();
    }

    return free_memory;
}

public static long sdCardUsed_bytes() {

    File   path        = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StatFs stat        = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long   free_memory = 0;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        free_memory = (stat.getBlockCountLong() - stat.getAvailableBlocksLong()) * stat.getBlockSizeLong(); //return value is in bytes
    } else {
        free_memory = (stat.getBlockCount() - stat.getAvailableBlocks()) * stat.getBlockSize(); //return value is in bytes
    }

    return free_memory;
}

public static long sdCardTotal_bytes() {

    File   path        = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    StatFs stat        = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long   free_memory = 0;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        free_memory = stat.getBlockCountLong() * stat.getBlockSizeLong(); //return value is in bytes
    } else {
        free_memory = stat.getBlockCount() * stat.getBlockSize(); //return value is in bytes
    }

    return free_memory;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getTotalSpace ()`, `getFreeSpace ()` or `getUsableSpace ()` https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

```
import java.io.File;
import android.util.Log;
....
File f = getMyFile();
Log.d("MyApp", f.getTotalSpace()+"");
....
```