# Can´t get device total storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I have a device with (External storage + sd card):

[image]

[image]

With the next code I get 8GB and not 31GB, Why?

How I can get the total space available?

```
private String getAvailableExternalMemorySize() {
    if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);
    } else {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

formatSize() is to get readable string from bytes.

Comment: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16835201/3743245 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will get internal storage path.

Please use below method to get external SD card path then you will use your method hope it will help you

```
private String getAvailableExternalMemorySize() {
    if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
        File path = new File(getExternalSdCardPath());
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);
    } else {
        return "Error";
    }
}


public static String getExternalSdCardPath() throws Throwable
    {
        String m_externalPath;
        m_externalPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
        return m_externalPath;
    }
```

Comment: In some devices works, and in others (all with sd card) I get "statfs  failed, errno: 2"