# Is there a way to get SD Card size in Android?

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, sd-card

I have tried every question related to this in Stack Overflow and Google and none of them works. I have tried something like this next link, but it returns the same as internal storage: [How to get an External storage sd card size (With Mounted SD card)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834964/how-to-get-an-external-storage-sd-card-size-with-mounted-sd-card/16835201#16835201)

For example, if I have about 12GB internal storage and 4GB SD card storage, no matter what method I use, I always get the exact same number for the SD space as I do for internal space.

It seems that the old methods posted here in Stack Overflow only works until Android KitKat but do not work in next android versions.

Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: Well wich path did you use? The code you posted has nothing to do with an sd card.

Comment: @greenapps   i tryed like 20 solutions posted in stack. Can't remember all of them. Simply tryed all of them. None of them works since 4.4 kitkat. Do you know a solution which works?

Comment: I dont know what you tried. And you did not tell which path you took for the sd card. If you only told the path.

Comment: @greenapps Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "df /mnt/sdcard",  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"); and i'm pretty sure i tryed more options, these are simply examples

Comment: Those functions do not deliver a path for a removable micro sd card. So no wonder that you did not succeed. You first should find the path for SD card.

Comment: @greenapps "real" path of the SD card could be different in each phone. Which is why knowing the full path for your phone doesn't help because it won't work on another phone. Hence the reason Google/Android recommends not to hardcode the path in the application. Knowing the path isn't going to help solve the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've always wondered this and couldn't find an answer online. So here's what I do.  It might not be so clean but it works for me every time.

For my case: it returns 61,055 MB. I have a 64 GB sd card inserted.

Oh and I forgot to mention: I did this on **Samsung Galaxy S5 6.0** and **Sony Xperia Z5 Premium 5.1.1** today to confirm. However, I also have an app that few hundred people use daily and I haven't experienced any issues yet.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
static String getExternalSdCardSize() {
    File storage = new File("/storage");
    String external_storage_path = "";
    String size = "";

    if (storage.exists()) {
        File[] files = storage.listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                try {
                    if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(file)) {
                        // storage is removable
                        external_storage_path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!external_storage_path.isEmpty()) {
        File external_storage = new File(external_storage_path);
        if (external_storage.exists()) {
            size = totalSize(external_storage);
        }
    }
    return size;
}

private static String totalSize(File file) {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(file.getPath());
    long blockSize, totalBlocks;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
    } else {
        blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    }

    return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
}

private static String formatSize(long size) {
    String suffix = null;

    if (size >= 1024) {
        suffix = "KB";
        size /= 1024;
        if (size >= 1024) {
            suffix = "MB";
            size /= 1024;
        }
    }

    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(size));

    int commaOffset = resultBuilder.length() - 3;
    while (commaOffset > 0) {
        resultBuilder.insert(commaOffset, ',');
        commaOffset -= 3;
    }

    if (suffix != null) resultBuilder.append(suffix);
    return resultBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. It's surprising to me how this isn't a very common question

Comment: Please, does it returns it's size also in GB

Answer (score 0):

My phone has a built-in storage of 32GB and SD Card of 15GB. Doing a `df` on `/mnt/sdcard` gives a 32GB result, which is not what we are looking for. Digging further, I found this `/storage` directory. It has 3 files in there:

```
shell@E5803:/storage $ ls
8E5D-12E2
emulated
self
```

doing a `df` on each item gives the following:

```
shell@E5803:/storage $ df self                                                 
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
self                   889.4M     0.0K   889.4M   4096
shell@E5803:/storage $ df emulated                                             
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
emulated                22.6G    10.8G    11.8G   4096
shell@E5803:/storage $ df 8E5D-12E2/                                           
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
8E5D-12E2/              14.9G     2.3G    12.7G   32768
```

I think the magic command is `"df /storage/" + mFilesArray[0]` where `mFilesArray[]` is the result from `ls /storage`.

(Let's hope that Google guys don't change the SD Card mount point in the future, which I doubt.)

Hope this helps.