# Is there something like the Linux free command on Android?

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, free-command

I'm porting an Linux C++ application to Android NDK and my app invokes `free` to the shell to see how much memory is available on the machine for logging purposes.  On my android port this fails with the error:

> sh: free: not found

On a Centos v4 Linux machine, I get back a result like this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8308648    3904076    4404572          0     454956    1593844
-/+ buffers/cache:    1855276    6453372
Swap:      2031608        208    2031400
```

Is there something else I can do here to approximate this on Android?

Comment: You can get it using the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it should work:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
Log.e("","Available MB : "+megAvailable);
```

Source: [Android-Droid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory)