# Invalid path error: get the external memory size

Tags: android

I am getting an error like below when I calling this to get External Memory Details.

```
05-07 16:55:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(22624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /storage/emulated/0
05-07 16:55:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(22624):    at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:46)
05-07 16:55:07.710: E/AndroidRuntime(22624):    at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:39)
```

It was works before i update my android to SAMSUNG Galaxy S3 4.3. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory?lq=1).This is my Code:

```
// getting available memory
public static String getAvailableExternalMemorySize() {
    if (externalMemoryAvailableBool()) {
        // File path =
        // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);

    } else {
        return ERROR;
    }

}

// getting total memory
public static String getTotalExternalMemorySize() {

    if (externalMemoryAvailableBool()) {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
        return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
    } else {
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

I want to get Available & Total Memory of my External Memory Card.

Comment: Where do you get exception?

Comment: There: >>> StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath());

Comment: On my Samsung Galaxy device that code works fine. Have You tried to use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: @sandrstar I have the write permission but still had the crash. Any other things I'm missing.

Comment: @SrikarReddy have you requested the permission dynamically (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request)?

Comment: @sandrstar I'm doing that too but the crash happened on 5.1 (<6).

Answer (score 1):

This is to help those who are looking for the same crash signature. Since this question came up on top when googling for it and I didn't see any clear accepted answer.

The suggestion by @sandrstar is correct. 
My apps experienced the same crash and I've resolved it just by adding READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
Though it seems crashes for my case only occurred/reported on 4.4 device.

The reason behind is explained here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Had the same problem. Adding the permission didn't help. The path to my SD card is /mnt/media_rw/extSdCard

Answer (score 0):

Use this snipped to get size of internal storage and external Sdcard

```
private Long getDiskSpaceTotalInBytes() {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    stat.restat(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    return stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getBlockCountLong();
}

private Long getDiskSpaceAvailableInBytes() {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    stat.restat(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    return stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
}

private static boolean hasRealRemovableSdCard(Context context) {
    File[] dirs = context.getExternalFilesDirs("");
    if (dirs.length >= 2 && dirs[1] != null) {
        return Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(dirs[1]);
    }
    return false;
}

private Long getSdCardSpaceAvailableInBytes(Context mContext) {
    if (!hasRealRemovableSdCard(mContext)) {
        return null;
    }
    File[] dirs = mContext.getExternalFilesDirs("");
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(dirs[1].getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
    return totalBlocks * blockSize;
}

private Long getSdCardSpaceTotalInBytes(Context mContext) {
    if (!hasRealRemovableSdCard(mContext)) {
        return null;
    }
    File[] dirs = mContext.getExternalFilesDirs("");
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(dirs[1].getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
    long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
    return availableBlocks * blockSize;
}
```