# How to get the actual values of Total Available space and storage of external SD card in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am Using Android Studio, I want to find the actual size of Sd card external storage at my phone by code.I have used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory option but it return 1.7 GB but mine is 8 GB. 
My Code:

```
StatFs statFs2 = new Stats(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
long blockSize2 = statFs2.getBlockSize();
final long totalSize2 = statFs2.getBlockCount() * blockSize2;
final long availableSize2 = statFs2.getAvailableBlocks() * blockSize2;
final long freeSize2 = statFs2.getFreeBlocks() * blockSize;
```

Please Help! Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android get free size of internal/external memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory)

Comment: I got that thanks any way.