# How to calculate free memory on Android when SD card is formatted as internal on M

Tags: android, storage

I am calculating the free internal storage space using the code below:

```
StatFs statInt = new StatFs(intPath);
bytesAvailableInt = (long) statInt.getAvailableBlocksLong() * (long) statInt.getBlockSizeLong();
```

where intPath is the path to the internal storage.

The above code works fine except the case where on Android M, the SD card is formatted as internal storage - in this case, the above code returns the real internal storage free space, not the real + sd card free space combined. Is there another way to do this, or I need to calculate the internal and sd free storage and add them up? If this is the case, is there a way to detect if the SD card is formatted as internal storage on the device?

Comment: Which path do you use as `intPath`?

Comment: I use Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath()

Comment: @a.p. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @YogeshRathi Sadly I don't have a way to try it out. Is it somehow possible to test it on emulator?

Comment: No, You can test on samsung s7 onwards any device, or any lenovo device , after android m

Comment: OK I got a Galaxy Note 8 with Android 8.0 (Oreo). How do I make this: "the SD card is formatted as internal storage" ? It only has the option to format it, but nothing more, and after formatting, it returns the correct values anyway. Are you sure Samsung didn't block this feature (probably because of bad performance on the SD-card compared to internal storage) ? Maybe you could add this into the question?