# External storage error, these are two errors, 1.ENOENT (No such file or directory) 2.Invalid path: /storage/extSdCard

Tags: android, android-studio

Logcat shows error in these lines in memorymethod.java
all errors related to `getexternalpath()` method which I given below in memorymothod.java code.

```
StatFs statFs2 = new StatFs(getExternalPath());
public static double getExternalUsedStorage()
{
    return Double.parseDouble(getExternalTotalMemory())-Double.parseDouble(getExternalFreeMemory());
}
```

Here is some code from `memorymethod.java` :

```
public static String getExternalPath()
{
     String sSDpath = null;
     File   fileCur = null;
     for( String sPathCur : Arrays.asList("MicroSD", "external_SD", "sdcard1", "ext_card", "external_sd", "ext_sd", "external", "extSdCard", "externalSdCard")) // external sdcard
     {
          fileCur = new File( "/mnt/", sPathCur);
          if( fileCur.isDirectory() && fileCur.canWrite())
          {
              sSDpath = fileCur.getAbsolutePath();
              break;
          }
          if( sSDpath == null)
          {
              fileCur = new File( "/storage/", sPathCur);
              if( fileCur.isDirectory() && fileCur.canWrite())
              {
                  sSDpath = fileCur.getAbsolutePath();
                  break;
              }
          }
          if( sSDpath == null)
          {
              fileCur = new File( "/storage/emulated", sPathCur);
              if( fileCur.isDirectory() && fileCur.canWrite())
              {
                  sSDpath = fileCur.getAbsolutePath();
                  //Log.e("path",sSDpath);
                  break;
              }               
        }
        fileCur = new File( "/storage/extSdCard");
        return fileCur.getAbsolutePath();
 }
```

Comment: Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() for getting external sdcard, /mnt/ will not work every where

Comment: Ranjan Das thanks for your response but it didn't work. i used your given code.

Comment: i only want to show the external storage(used and total) in progress bar. i am developing booster app,

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
String fileName="abc.txt";

File file = new File(fileName);

File dirAsFile = file.getParentFile();
```

use this code u will get path of ur file using external or internal storage path

Comment: Thanks rahul for your reply. I don't need to get file but i only want to show the external storage(used and total) in progress bar. i am developing booster app,

Comment: public static long getExternalStorageAvailableSpace() {
    long availableSpace = -1L;
    try {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath());
        stat.restat(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        availableSpace = (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) stat.getBlockSize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return availableSpace;
}

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get a particular file

```
File dir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PersonData");
File file   =   new File(dir, "Data.pdf");
```

Here Data.pdf is the file name, inside my "PersonData" named folder in external storage

Comment: Ranjan i don't file but i want to show the storage(used and total) in progress bar.

Comment: Use this link , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
public static long getExternalStorageAvailableSpace() {
    long availableSpace = -1L;
    try {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()                .getPath());
        stat.restat(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        availableSpace = (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) stat.getBlockSize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return availableSpace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i thing you have not
 add this two permission in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```