# What should be the file format that is handling very large text data to be saved

Tags: android, file, size, limit

When you are storing a text in a file and keep on adding to it, than is there any size limit for the file? Can some crash or error lead to a loss. The app needs to save a month long diary data.

Comment: Any file format can be "large in size".

Comment: Why are you asking this?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Iam asking for my file should stay safe for long period.

Comment: @Snowrain, sorry I still don't understand the question, please add more details

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Basically what I wanna ask is that when you are storing a text in a file and keeping on adding than is there any size limit for a .text file. Any crash or  mishappening can lead to a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any file format. For being safe from *large size* expect a `OutOfMemoryException` while handling a large file. So handle a (expected) large file with a `OutOfMemoryException` catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can defiantly run out of memory when handling large files, there for a good idea will be to check the available space before writing to the file.

You can find how to do this in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8133437/1129332