# How to get the android system size?

Tags: android, size, storage, system, device

I'm looking to get the android system size programmatically (In fact, my intention is to find the entire storage of the device. But the functions that returns the phone's memory ignore the occupied memory of the Android system):

[image]

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory

Comment: thanks, but not really ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get internal total memory size this way:

```
double totalSize = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().toString()).getTotalSpace();
double totMb = totalSize / (1024 * 1024);
```

And you can get internal free size this way:

```
double availableSize = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().toString()).getFreeSpace();
    double freeMb = availableSize/ (1024 * 1024);
```

Also the code to get external free and total memory size:

```
long freeBytesExternal =  new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()).getFreeSpace();
       int free = (int) (freeBytesExternal/ (1024 * 1024));
        long totalSize =  new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()).getTotalSpace();
        int total= (int) (totalSize/ (1024 * 1024));
       String availableMb = free+"Mb out of "+total+"MB";
```

The sum of this sizes is the total available system size!

Comment: getTotalSpace does not returns the real device storage (  ignore the occupied memory of the Android system)

Comment: @MohammadFazel Try using this method: double availableSize = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().toString()).getFreeSpace();

Comment: Thanks but i'm not looking to get device free space...

Comment: @MohammadFazel simply replace free with total!: 
`double availableSize = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().toString()).getTotalSpace();`

Comment: As I've said above : getTotalSpace does not returns the real device storage ( ignore the occupied memory of the Android system)

Comment: @user924 I honestly don't remember