# Getting the available storage size of external storage (removable SD card inclusive) on Android

Tags: android

How do I programatically get the available storage size of both external storage and a mounted SD card storage of a android device.

Comment: this is secret information

Comment: File.getTotalSpace() is your friend.

Comment: @Style: It's seriously needed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android get free size of internal/external memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory)