# How put the free memory info in a texview

Tags: android, memory, textview, activity-manager, getmem

How can i put this in a textview?

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
memoryInfo.availMem;
```

the textview id is for example `freemem`. The textview is in a second tab of a swipeview.thans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your layout XML

```
  <TextView android:id="@+id/myTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

and this in your activity:

```
   TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
    myTextView.setText("" + memoryInfo.availMem);
```

memoryInfo.availMem is the available memory on the system.
 memoryInfo.totalMem is the total memory accessible by the kernel.

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8826524/793607) to a good answer about memory availability.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to see the total RAM and the avaible RAM?

Comment: posted memory stuff in my answer.