# How to measure size/capacity of /data/data/com.**.**/ folder in android

Tags: android

I need to download some data files into my  `/data/data/com.**.**/` folder.

Before that I need to total capacity of my  `/data/data/com.**.**/` folder.

I tried in `Settings -> Application -> All` tab , there it is showing `260MB` used and `1.7GB` free for my current device.

So can I assume it as I can download upto `1.7GB` in my application.

Please let me know if there's any other way to measure the capacity of the `/data/data/com.**.**/`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595334/get-free-space-on-internal-memory/4595449#4595449

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.getFreeSpace()` to get the free disk space available for a certain path.