# Parsing adb output

Tags: android, parsing, storage, adb

after using

```
adb shell df
```

How to parse the text to eliminate spaces under Free column ?

```
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                   483M    52K   483M   4096
/mnt/secure            483M     0K   483M   4096
/mnt/asec              483M     0K   483M   4096
/mnt/obb               483M     0K   483M   4096
/system                788M   720M    67M   4096
/data                    1G   513M     1G   4096
/cache                 123M     4M   118M   4096
/mnt/cd-rom              4M     4M     0K   2048
/protect_f               8M     4M     4M   4096
/protect_s               8M     4M     4M   4096
```

the main goal is to calculate the sum of free space.

Comment: not much info. language? and why use adb?

Comment: just simple way to code a hole apk from scratch to calculate the sum of free space

Comment: If its an Android app, you can parse using Java. However, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595334/get-free-space-on-internal-memory

Comment: You do realize that the sum of all values in the "Free" column does not have any meaningful value, right?

Comment: for data, system and cache

Answer (score 0):

As there are no language restrictions within your question at this time, in `Bash`...

```sh
adb shell df -BM | awk '{if(NR>1) print $4}'
```

... should output the fourth column and by using the `-BM` option with the `df` command one can avoid headaches when there's partitions with gigabytes or more of available space.

However, do note that `df` output may vary so I'd suggest looking to the `man` and `--help` documentation as there's a `--total` option that might be easier to deal with...

```
adb shell df -BM --total | tail -1
```