# Glide, Clear cache when cache size is larger than 50 mb

Tags: android, android-glide, cache-control, image-loading

I am using Glide library for image loading. There is lot of images in my app so I want to clear cache once cache size is larger than 50 mb. 
Can someone help me to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call Glide.get(context).clearDiskCache() on outside the UI thread. (also consider clearMemory() too to prevent surprises after clearing disk cache) this worked for me

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
             Glide.get(MainActivity.this).clearDiskCache();
          }
     }).start();
```

> There is lot of images in my app so I want to clear cache once cache size is larger than 50 mb.

in case you want to put limit 50 mb you can implement glide module

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.util.Log;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule;
import com.example.MyApplication;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LimitCacheSizeGlideModule implements GlideModule {
    // Modern device should have 8GB (=7.45GiB) or more!
    private static final int SMALL_INTERNAL_STORAGE_THRESHOLD_GIB = 6;
    private static final int DISK_CACHE_SIZE_FOR_SMALL_INTERNAL_STORAGE_MIB = 50*1024*1024;

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        if (MyApplication.from(context).isTest()) return; // NOTE: StatFs will crash on robolectric.

        double totalGiB = getTotalBytesOfInternalStorage() / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
        Log.i(String.format(Locale.US, "Internal Storage Size: %.1fGiB", totalGiB));
        if (totalGiB < SMALL_INTERNAL_STORAGE_THRESHOLD_GIB) {
            Log.i("Limiting image cache size to " + DISK_CACHE_SIZE_FOR_SMALL_INTERNAL_STORAGE_MIB + "MiB");
            builder.setDiskCache(new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, DISK_CACHE_SIZE_FOR_SMALL_INTERNAL_STORAGE_MIB));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
    }

    private long getTotalBytesOfInternalStorage() {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/4595449/1474113
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            return getTotalBytesOfInternalStorageWithStatFs(stat);
        } else {
            return getTotalBytesOfInternalStorageWithStatFsPreJBMR2(stat);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    private long getTotalBytesOfInternalStorageWithStatFs(StatFs stat) {
        return stat.getTotalBytes();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private long getTotalBytesOfInternalStorageWithStatFsPreJBMR2(StatFs stat) {
        return (long) stat.getBlockSize() * stat.getBlockCount();
    }
}
```

and then in your manifest add it like this

```
<manifest

    ...

    <application>

        <meta-data
            android:name="YourPackageNameHere.LimitCacheSizeGlideModule"
            android:value="GlideModule" />

        ...

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: How I will get know the current cache size so that I will call above method once current cache size will cross 50 MB?

Comment: Once I set the limit to 50 MB, is there any need to clear cache using  Glide.get(MainActivity.this).clearDiskCache(); or library will automatically do that?

Comment: no @SapnaSharma it will set the limit you need not to clear it manually it will be done automatically

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: I have implemented GlideModule and added meta-data in manifest. Now when LimitCacheSizeGlideModule  will get call as there is no logs(added in above code)showing when I am running this code.

Comment: are you using pro-gaurd in your project?

Comment: Yes I am using pro-gaurd but for debug build I disabled it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138109/discussion-between-sapna-sharma-and-digvijay-singh).